# How can I backup a SQL Server 2008 database and restore it again

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-backups

My PC is running slow. I want to format it but my asp project database is in SQL Server 2008, I know how to backup the database but a friend of mine told me it won't be restored if you format your system, backup only gets restored if you use same computer, SQL Server. I'm really confused, but I have to format my PC in any case. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to save my database?

Comment: Your friend is wrong. Create a backup file by right click/backup. You can restore that into a new install of SQL Server, as long at is the same or higher version.

Comment: Also: all the searching on **Google** or **Bing** hasn't returned ***any*** results for you?!?!?!?

Comment: thanks . i did search it, but  reinstalling windows and restoring backup was not mentioned.  that is what confused me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right Click on your Database which you want to take as backup .Then Go to `Task>Backup`
2. While doing backup select the drive which you are not going to Format and keep back there.
3. For Restoring. Right Click on `Databases`{Top one} and select Restore option.
4. Select `From Device` option.
5. While Restoring Select the file which you created as backup by browsing. If you are not able to find that backup file, then make sure you have specified Files Type as `All`.

and yes your Friend is wrong :)